# How to pass bean values from parent jsp to child jsp in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

How to pass bean values from parent jsp to child jsp in struts2?

My current application is built on Struts 1.2.
In this, when the form is submitted, entire jsp is submitted. And another (or same) jsp is loaded with the bean values.

I am trying to implement a single page application in my current application. Instead of loading/submitting entire page, I'm calling the jsp through ajax. It returns the html of the required jsp and the html is appended in the main jsp.

So there is only 1 main jsp which is redirected through struts action.

I'm calling the bean values in the main jsp.

My requirement is that when the user clicks any control input, How can I pass the bean values(data) to the new jsp which is loaded in the main jsp through ajax.

How can I pass the bean values(data) to the new jsp?

I'm novice to struts2. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edited:

Please find the code which appends the html through ajax:

The div in which the html is appended:

```
JSP:

<div class="dynamic-loaded-content">
</div>
```

and HTML name which is loaded on ajax: index-calender.html
This name is passed in the following method:

```
JS:

function dynamic_file_linker(path) { /* loader display */
$('.loading-bg').show();
$('.loading-img').show().offset({
    top: $(window).height() / 2,
    left: $(window).width() / 2
});
$('.tool-tip').hide();

$.ajax({
    url: path,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(result) {
        $('.dynamic-loaded-content').empty().append(result);

        $('.loading-bg').fadeOut();
        page_align();
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Sorry! The page cannot be loaded.');
    }
})
}
```

Comment: AJAX calls must point to Actions, not JSPs. Those Actions then will return JSPs. Can you show us what have you done until now ? BTW Struts2 is absolutely able to achieve the result, but consider it may not be the best choice for an SPA: there are frameworks born exactly with that in mind... and hence more SPA-oriented. I would take a look at AngularJS, just in case, since you are starting now studying a new framework and have "custom" requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can pass form data over AJAX using the FormData object:

```
var formData = new FormData(form);
xmlHTTP.send(formData);
```

Where `xmlHTTP` is your ajax request object and `form` is your form. This will pass all the data from the form to the action you are calling.

See here for details of this technique:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 0):

Ajax function

```
 $.ajax({
 url: path?form_data1='+ $("#data1").val()+'&form_data2='+$("#data2").val()+',
 type: 'GET',
 success: function(result) {
 //your stuff     
 },
 error: function() {
    alert('Sorry! The page cannot be loaded.');
 }
});
```

struts.xml

```
 <action name="path" class="controller.UrlActionClass">
        <result name="success">result.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

UrlActionClass.class

```
   private String form_data1;
   private String form_data2;
   //getter and setter method
```

ajax success page...
   placed the result.jsp page to your div tag.